How to import multiple things from multiple js files and use the variable by accordingly
I have multiple js files in the structure, for example
lib
├─ a
│  ├─ file_a_01.js
│  ├─ file_a_02.js
│  ├─ file_a_03.js
├─ b
│  ├─ file_b_01.js
│  ├─ file_b_02.js
├─ c
│  ├─ file_c_01.js
├─ d
   ├─ file_d_01.js
   ├─ file_d_02.js
   ├─ file_d_03.js
   ├─ file_d_04.js

The folder and js file number are random, but they all have a file name pattern. and every file have only 1 export with the same name with the file name, for example:
// file_a_01.js
export let file_a_01 = [1,2,3,4,5]

How do I import those files, and how to filter the variable name based on the logic:
import {file_a_01} from '/lib/a/file_a_01'
import {file_a_02} from '/lib/a/file_a_02'
import {file_a_03} from '/lib/a/file_a_03'

import {file_b_01} from '/lib/b/file_a_01'
import {file_b_02} from '/lib/b/file_a_02'

if (someCondition == "A") {
    if (otherCondition == 1) {
        // use file_a_01
    } else if (otherCondition == 2) {
        // use file_a_02
    } else if (otherCondition == 3) {
        // use file_a_03
    }
} else if (someCondition == "B") {
    if (otherCondition == 1) {
        // use file_b_01
    } else if (otherCondition == 2) {
        // use file_b_02
    } 
}

I can't write those code if I have hundreds of them. I am thinking for using for loop but I must know the number of files under every folder, and must store them as an array. However, I don't think I can use string method such as file_${someCondition}_${otherCondition}, because it will read as a string, not the variable name.

Use a dynamic import(file_${condition}), you can use await to get the imported module synchronously in a for loop

@Jon can you give an example? I can grasp the idea, but not all the implementation. And another thing, how do I know the number of files in the directory and do the loop number accordingly.

well apparently someone thought the question was answered already, typical stackoverflow. if you're talking about node.js the linked answer will probably help. if you want to know about files in a directory in the browser, it doesn't normally have an API for this for security purposes. depends on what you need.

@Jon well, the linked answer didn't directly answer my question, but of that answer, I had to change my method, and now it works.
